# Remove non zero values from dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary of dictionary as below how to remove non zero key,values from this

```
{'abcdef': {'1987': 0.0,
  '0544': 0.0,
   '0568': 0.0,
  '3000': 0.0,
  '7095': 0.0,
  '75609': 1.0,
  '56565': 2.0,
  '98656': 3.0,
  '756095': 0.0,
  '23432': 0.0},
  'fgrd': {'1987': 0.0,
  '0544': 0.0,
   '0568': 0.0,
  '3000': 0.0,
  '7095': 0.0,
  '75609': 1.0,
  '56565': 2.0,
  '98656': 3.0,
  '756095': 0.0,
  '23432': 0.0}

}
```

Tried below,
{key:val for key, val in my_dict.items() if val.values() != 0.0}

and getting AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'values',

Thanks

Comment: Show your code, then we can help fixing it.

Comment: `{k_o: {k_i: v_i for k_i, v_i in v_o.items() if not v_i} if isinstance(v_o, dict) else v_o for k_o, v_o in d.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate over the primary dictionary and than look for values in secondary dict
here is an example:

```
val = {'abcdef': {'1987': 0.0,
  '0544': 0.0,
   '0568': 0.0,
  '3000': 0.0,
  '7095': 0.0,
  '75609': 1.0,
  '56565': 2.0,
  '98656': 3.0,
  '756095': 0.0,
  '23432': 0.0}}

for dict_k in val:
    for dicts in val.values():
        for k in dicts.copy():
            if dicts[k] != 0.0:
                dicts.pop(k)
print(val)
```

Comment: Outer loop: `for key, value in val.items():`. Inner loop `for i_key, i_value in reversed(value.items()):`. If you want to pop items from sequence you're iterating over just do it backwards.